# $y=2x$ and $y^2-xy=8$

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

I'm stuck with this problem that my teacher gave me it's supposed to be a simulation equation but I have no clue what to do can you give me a step by step solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first step is to substitute for $y$ in terms of $x$, using the first equation to simplify the second equation.  I think you mean "simultaneous equations" rather than a "simulation equation".

Comment: Thank you and yes I did mean simultaneous equations

Comment: I got x=2 or -2 and y=4 but this doesn't work what should I do

Comment: What do you mean "this doesn't work"? Can you explain what your problem is?

Comment: If you use y=4 and substitute it into the second equation you don't get 8

Comment: You are making progress, but perhaps have made a sign mistake.  Note that if $x=2$ then $y=4$ (check it works), but if $x=-2$, then $y=-4$ (again check that this works).

Comment: But even if you use x=-2 -4² would be 16, 16--2-4 is then 14 and I you use 2 then you end up with 10 and I'm not sure what to do at this point

Comment: Use parentheses and I'm sure you will see the error.  You are multiplying $-xy$ where $x=-2$ and $y=-4$.

Comment: Thank you so much you where right I needed to add brackets and after it got me the right answer

Answer (score 5):

with $y=2x$ we get in the second equation $$4x^2-2x^2=8$$

Answer (score 1):

You are given the equation:
$$y^2 - xy = \{8 : y = 2x \}$$
So just replace $y$ with $2x$:
$$\begin{align} \implies 8 &= (2x)^2 - xy \\ &= 4x^2 - xy \\ &= x(4x - y) \\ &= x(4x - 2x) \\ &= 2x^2 \\ \implies x^2 &= 8/2 \\ &= 4 \\ \therefore x &= \pm\sqrt{4} \\ &= \pm 2 \\ \therefore y &= \pm 4 \end{align}$$.
$$: \ = \text{ such that}$$
$$\implies \ = \text{ which implies that}$$
$$\therefore \ = \text{ therefore}$$
$$\pm \ = \text{ positive or negative (plus or minus)}$$